# Using Inline::Python in a mod_perl handler

Tags: python, apache, perl, segmentation-fault, mod-perl

Is there a known trick to be able to create a [`mod_perl`](http://perl.apache.org/) handler that uses some slightly involved [`Inline::Python`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-Python/Python.pod)?

I have created the following handler:

```
package ApacheHandler::Test;

use 5.010;
use autodie;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;

use Inline Config => DIRECTORY => '/tmp/inline';

use Apache2::Const;
use Apache2::Request    ();
use Apache2::RequestRec ();
use Apache2::RequestIO  ();

use Inline Python => <<EOF;

#import numpy

def hello():
    return "Hello!"

EOF

sub handler {
  my $r = Apache2::Request->new(shift);
  $r->content_type("text/plain");
  $r->print( hello() );
  return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

1;
```

It works just fine, as long as `import numpy` remains commented out. If I uncomment this line, Apache segfaults *immediately on restart* and I see something like this in `dmesg`:

> [9136481.110798] /usr/sbin/apach[10933]: segfault at 7f83df8e6749 ip 00007f83df2aa470 sp 00007fffa1ebe818 error 4 in libpython2.7.so.1.0[7f83df1c5000+281000]

Note that `numpy` was installed through `pip`. I have tried importing some other packages installed through `pip`, which are in the same location (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`), and got the same problem.

I have tried with those lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

That changed nothing. I ran out of imagination for things to try and have tried enabling and disabling `mod_python`, with no change.

Additionally, I have tried running the same script, adapted as a CGI, and *it worked.*

I have tried was entirely unable to start Apache inside `gdb`, so I don't have a more exact error message, but I hope I have pinpointed the problem exactly enough for someone that knows more about `mod_perl` or Python or `Inline` to be able to see what's going on.

**Update: Additional but not very useful debugging information**

I just had what seemed like a good idea: load [`Apache2::Reload`,](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2%3a%3aReload) restart Apache with a "correct" handler (i.e. `import` commented out), attach `gdb` to one of Apache's children, remove the `#` in the handler's Python and load the page.

It didn't segfault, but I *did* get a useful message in the error log:

> [Sun Jun 01 11:24:46 2014] [error] [client 152.81.2.175] Couldn't make directory path '/tmp/inline/lib/auto/ApacheHandler/Test_771f'.\n\n at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/ApacheHandler/Test.pm line 16.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/ApacheHandler/Test.pm line 23.\nCompilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Apache2/Reload.pm line 181.\n

This pointed to a very real problem: many paths in `/tmp/inline` had been created by root. So I did `chown -R www-data /tmp/inline`, which *made the handler with `import` work* (!), but when I restarted Apache, it segfaulted again, notwithstanding the fact that everything under `/tmp/inline` was *still* writable by both root and www-data.

So, unless I misunderstand what happened here, I have still not found how to make Apache and `Inline::Python` work together.

Comment: Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @user44400, Sadly no. I ended up splitting my application into a frontend that ran through `mod_perl` and a backend that ran as a daemon and did all the heavy lifting.